# Is it possible to have a single SSL certificate with IP address and domain name?

Tags: ssl-certificate

We want to have a single SSL certificate for a web site so that the website can be accessed with a domain name and IP address. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

Yup, when the `SAN` field of the SSL certificate contains the `IP:XXX.XX.XX.XXX` value it's possible to successfully connect to such a service without warnings (for a known CA, of course).

But in reality this has to be supported by the CA you are buying the certificate from. In my experience I don't remember seeing such options in commercial CA web interfaces, though this doesn't mean you won't find one.

Comment: Note that IP address must be duplicated as DNS Name as well. That is, SAN should consist of at least 3 entries: DNSName=FQDN,DNSName=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,IPAddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: GoDaddy sells these multi-domain certificates, so I'm sure you can buy them elsewhere too.

Comment: i have created two SSL certificate, 1 with IP and other with DNS. i have imoprted both the certificates into single keystore. Now i wanted to use both certificates for web site, so that website can be accessed with IP and DNS. is it possible?

Comment: @Crypt32, could you verify? I know, it is `DNS:FQDN`. Are you sure, it is `IPAddress=` rather than `IP:`?